# how to get current directory for executing batch file from current directory?

Tags: windows, batch

I have a batch file(lunch.bat) to run which has command to run another batch file(main.bat). I copyied this two files in my pendrive. I know my pendrive's drive latter in my computer,that's why i can configure 1st batch file(lunch.bat) to run another batch on my computer. But when i copy this two files in my pendrive and insert it to another computer, 1st batch file can't run another batch file. So this is a problem for me. Can anybody help me to get current directory command  like c++(GetCurrentDirectory) function to run batch from any computer and from any drive?

Answer (score 3):

From [Raymond Chen](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050128-00/?p=36573)

> The easy way is to use the %CD% pseudo-variable. It expands to the current working directory.

```
set OLDDIR=%CD%
.. do stuff ..
chdir /d %OLDDIR% &rem restore current directory
```

Answer (score 1):

Batch command `cd` typed in without any parameters will return current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in the `lunch.bat` file:

```
call %~dp0main.bat
```

This starts the `main.bat` from the same drive & folder as the `lunch.bat`, wherever it is.